# Import module scope and variables

Tags: python, import, namespaces

My question is about python 2.7 namespaces and module imports. My problem is understanding why this works:
If I have a module file memory.py:

```
memory={}
def insert_into(a,b):
   memory[a]=b
```

And then two files mod1.py and mod2.py with similar code:
mod1.py:

```
import memory
memory.insert_into('a',1)
```

mod2.py:

```
 import memory
 memory.insert_into('b',2)
```

and finally a test.py file which I run as a script:

```
import mod1,mod2
```

Somehow if I test:

```
mod1.memory.memory is mod2.memory.memory
```

It return True. Is this expected? At what point do the namespaces of mod1 and mod2 become entangled?
Sorry if my question does not make sense, it is my first time.

Comment: Based on your code, `mod1.memory` exists, but I wouldn't think `mod1.memory.memory` would exist.  I'm hesitant to attempt to debug this further until I understand that.

Comment: And for the record, when I try this I get that `mod1.memory is mod2.memory` returns `False`.

Comment: There is only one object so what would you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They don't get mangled at all. You simply import the same object in two places, so naturally Python reports it is the same.

Comment: Of course!  Thanx, I should have thought of it before.

Answer (score 0):

In Python a module acts like a singleton on its own. 
What you are seeing is the effect of that.

Answer (score 0):

You may note that with `mod1.memory.memory` or `mod2.memory.memory` actually you didn't updated the `memory` dictionary in those modules,but each o them are a `module` object and both refer to same object (an empty dictionary (`memory={}`))and as  `x is y` is true if and only if x and y are the same object the result here is True.

So in `test.py` you can try :

```
print mod1.memory.memory
print mod2.memory.memory
```